# Combinatorics: Creating a password with characters, numbers, and one special character

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have a question that goes as follows

> A password must consist of $16$ characters. Each character can be a digit ($0 − 9$), an uppercase or lowercase letter ($A-Z$, $a-z$) or one out of ten special characters. How many valid passwords are there?

I think it would be $P(62,15) + P(10,1)$, but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there are no restrictions, the answer would be 72^16 since there are 72 options for each of the 16 places.